# Unused alias showing that it is used

Tags: rest, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am offering a RESTful service in an OSGi- based application. The class I am using has the following paths shown in the snippet below:

```
@Path("shoes")
public class ShoeService extends ShoeMakerImpl
{
      .
      .
      .

   @Override
   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   @Path("{shoename}")
   public String getFunctionalURL(@PathParam("shoename") String shoeName)
  {
      .
      // do some shoe stuff
      .
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I load and activate the bundle that contains this class, I get the following message:

```
[WARNING] Failed to register servlet for /shoes
org.osgi.service.http.NamespaceException: Alias /shoes is already in use.
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.service.SharedHttpServiceImpl.registerServlet(SharedHttpServiceImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.service.PerBundleHttpServiceImpl.registerServlet(PerBundleHttpServiceImpl.java:217)
    at org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard.internal.manager.ServletMapping.register(ServletMapping.java:43)
    at org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard.internal.manager.ExtenderManager.registerAll(ExtenderManager.java:243)
    at org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard.internal.manager.ExtenderManager.setHttpService(ExtenderManager.java:203)
    at org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard.internal.tracker.HttpServiceTracker.added(HttpServiceTracker.java:37)
    at org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard.internal.tracker.HttpServiceTracker.added(HttpServiceTracker.java:24)
    at org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard.internal.tracker.AbstractTracker.addingService(AbstractTracker.java:42)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:870)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:901)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:987)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:838)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:545)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4560)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3542)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:348)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.service.HttpServiceFactory.start(HttpServiceFactory.java:113)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.HttpServiceController.register(HttpServiceController.java:116)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.init(DispatcherServlet.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:612)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.felix.http.jetty.internal.JettyService.initializeJetty(JettyService.java:269)
    at org.apache.felix.http.jetty.internal.JettyService.startJetty(JettyService.java:201)
    at org.apache.felix.http.jetty.internal.JettyService.start(JettyService.java:134)
    at org.apache.felix.http.jetty.internal.JettyActivator.doStart(JettyActivator.java:60)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.AbstractActivator.start(AbstractActivator.java:41)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:697)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2220)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2138)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:977)
    at aQute.launcher.Launcher.update(Launcher.java:457)
    at aQute.launcher.Launcher.activate(Launcher.java:354)
    at aQute.launcher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:238)
    at aQute.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:87)
```

I have not created any other "aliases" with the same name (that I am aware of). I have changed the name in the path several times, once even to "xxxgggc" (for example: @Path("xxxgggc")).

I get the same message, regardless of what I put in that @Path annotation:

```
[WARNING] Failed to register servlet for /xxxgggc
org.osgi.service.http.NamespaceException: Alias /shoes is already in use.
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.service.SharedHttpServiceImpl.registerServlet(SharedHttpServiceImpl.java:74)
      .
      .
      Don't need to repeat the stack trace
```

I probably wouldn't care about this warning, but I cannot access the service at the path. When I attempt to do so, using the proper RESTful URL (http://localhost:8080/shoes/wingtip), I get the following:

```
HTTP ERROR: 500

Problem accessing /shoes/wingtip. Reason:

java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this odd behaviour, and (more importantly) how to fix whatever problem I am having?

Someone please advise...

[Edited Addition:]

Below is a list of the bundles I am using at runtime.

```
-runbundles: \
com.shoeshine.demo.gateway;version=snapshot,\
osgi.cmpn;version='[5.0.0,5.0.1)',\
org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard,\
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations,\
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core,\
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind,\
com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-base,\
com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider,\
org.amdatu.web.rest.jaxrs,\
org.amdatu.web.rest.wink,\
org.apache.felix.dependencymanager,\
org.apache.felix.http.api,\
org.apache.felix.http.base,\
org.apache.felix.http.jetty,\
org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api,\
com.shoeshine.demo.web;version=latest,\
org.apache.felix.gogo.command,\
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,\
org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
```

Comment: It depends on how this REST class is being picked up and registered with the HttpService. Probably it's being registered by two different actors. There isn't enough detail here to tell what is going on. As for the `NullPointerException`, the stack trace for that might give some clues.

Comment: That is an interesting thought. Do yu know how I can discover what actors are registering the service? Also: what other details can I supply that would help discover what is happening?

Comment: Well, what framework or bundle are you using to register the REST service? You've shown a code sample that contains a JAX-RS service implementation, but this will not be registered by magic. Something has to pick it up and use it. In other words: what is your stack?

Comment: I am not using Felix or CXF, if that is what you are asking. The OSGi container I am using is Felix. I am using the Jetty bundle that is available and several JAX-RS bundles. Please see my edited question for a list of the runtime bundles I am using. Please let me know i there is other required information...

Comment: Almost forgot to mention: I am also using amdatu bundles for the REST support...

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with Amdatu, but I wonder if you actually need both the Amdatu REST bundles *and* Felix HTTP Whiteboard? I have a suspicion that these are overlapping in functionality, which would explain the dual registration.